# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes, but it is just a standardization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, valueerror

I am trying to use my model to predict a new feature with the following numbers:

array1=np.array([[5.4629,0.21,1646732.8000,490188.7170,3521510.1690,96.8,27.70,118.30]])

array1=scaler.transform(array1)

model.predict(array1) ### this one could not be processed yet due to the error from previous command line:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,8) (9,) (1,8)

The problem is: I am just making a scaler transform using sklearn MinMaxScaler, with what dimentions should match if it is just a standardization? I've reading differents sources and they are always making operations between 2 arrays, so it makes sense at least one dimention match, but in this case I could not understand what it is going on...
Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: could you post more code in terms of how you set up the scaler object?

Comment: Sure! thank you in advance!

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler()

Comment: Did you run `scaler.fit(array1)`?

Comment: I tried, but now a similar error appeared:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 9 but received input with shape [None, 8]